# Where is python installed on my Ubuntu Mate

Tags: python3

I was configuring my sublime text to work with python but I don't know where python is installed. I used the command `which python` but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On installed system Python is available as `python3`.

Python2 is deprecated, so you can make symlink between `python` and `python3` by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

and then Python 3 will be available as `python` too.